# Spring Boot RestAPI Unit Test Issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have two controller `User` and `Role`. I write unit test for my controller, but I get following exception while running test cases. Please correct me where I'm wrong.

Description:

```
Field repository in uk.co.circuare.cube.service.user.api.UserController required a bean of type 'uk.co.circuare.cube.service.user.repository.UserRepository' that could not be found.
The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'uk.co.circuare.cube.service.user.repository.UserRepository' in your configuration.
```

Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication 
@ComponentScan({
    "uk.co.circuare.cube.service.user",
    "uk.co.circuare.cube.service.user.api",
    "uk.co.circuare.cube.service.api.advice"
}) 
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

RoleControllerTest

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = RoleController.class)
public class RoleControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @MockBean
    private RoleRepository repository;
    
}
```

UserControllerTest

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = UserController.class)
public class UserControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper;

    @MockBean
    private UserRepository repository;
}
```

Comment: apparently, you haven't provided a Bean of UserRepository, so the UserController can't autowire it. You may want to show some of the relevant code. Either way, that is your problem

Comment: @SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"uk.co.circuare.cube.service.user","uk.co.circuare.cube.service.user.api","uk.co.circuare.cube.service.api.advice"})
public class Application {
  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}

Comment: i have added controllers and mainclass

Comment: no, you haven't. also: please don't put code in a comment, that is not readable. Put it correctly formatted in the question

Comment: @Repository
public interface RoleRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Role, Long> { 
 Optional<Role> findByName(String name); }

Comment: @Repository
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> { 
 Optional<User> findByEmailAddress(String emailAddress);
}

Comment: @Stultuske please check now

Comment: don't put code in comments.

Comment: Add code in your question with import statement packages